# How to split a file into lines using foreach in linux?

Tags: linux, file, foreach, split, cat

File.txt has numerous lines with paths to different files

I want each line of File.txt to become an argument to sed command

Ex :
File.txt has following lines

```
dir1/sub1/a.txt
dir2/sub2/b.txt
dir3/sub3/c.txt
```

Need to use `sed` command on all these files in File.txt by splitting File.txt into lines and using
`foreach` command

How can I do that in
`Linux`
terminal? Please let me know if there are any other methods as well

Comment: `sed` works line by line by default.

Comment: What to you want to accomplish ? Splitting the lines by the \n delimiter and reading it into an BASH array ?

Comment: @EmanuelP I want each line of File.txt to become argument of sed command

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xargs` like so:

```
xargs -a File.txt -I '::' echo Hello ::
```

- `-a File.txt` reads items from `File.txt` (otherwise `xargs` would work with stdin and pipes)
- `-I '::'` makes `::` a placeholder for the line read from the file that can be used in the following command

You would put your `sed` command at the end (instead of `echo`) and use `::` instead of the filenames from `File.txt`.

I am not sure what you mean with `foreach` in your question.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried this command with {} but it somehow didn't work

Comment: I set `::` as placeholder, either use `::` in your sed command line or use `{}` with xargs and its `-I` argument.

You could edit your question, that it shows what you are trying to accomplish. At the moment we can only guess how you want to use `sed`.